# How can python auto scrape on a daily basis given certain url change rules?

Tags: python

Hi new comer in the python learning. Sales man travel a lot, would like to save some bucks in the hotel booking, so I am using python to scrape certain hotels on certain days for personal use.

I can use python to scrape a specific webpage, but im having trouble in making a serial search.

The single webpage scrape goes like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ="http://hotelname.com/arrivalDate=05%2F23%2F2016**&departureDate=05%2F24%2F2016" #means arrive on May23 and leaves on May 
wb_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
names = soup.select('.PropertyName')
prices = soup.select('.RateSection ')
for name,price in zip(names,prices):

 data = {
    "name":name.get_text(),
    "price":price.get_text()
}
print (data)
```

By doing this I can get the price of the hotels on that day. But I would like to know the price in a longer period(say 15 days), so I can arrange my travel and save some bucks. The question is how can I make the search auto loop itself?

eg. hotelname('') price(200USD)  May 1 Check in(CI) and May 2 check out(CO)

hotelname('') price(150USD) May 2 CI May 3 CO

..........

hotelname('') price(170USD) May30 CI May 31 CO

Hope I make my intentions clear. Can someone help guide in what way should I do to achieve this auto search? It is too much work to manually change the date in the urls. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *datetime* lib to get the dates and increment a day at a time in the loop for n days:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def n_booking(n):
    # start tomorrow
    bk = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
    # check next n days
    for i in range(n): 
        mon, day, year = bk.month, bk.day, bk.year
        # go to next day
        bk = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
        d_mon, d_day, d_year = bk.month, bk.day, bk.year
        url ="http://hotelname.com/arrivalDate=d{mon}%2F{day}%2F{year}**&departureDate={d_mon}%2F{d_day}%2F{d_year}"\
            .format(mon=mon, day=day, year=year, d_day=d_day, d_mon=d_mon,d_year=d_year)
        wb_data = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
        names = soup.select('.PropertyName')
        prices = soup.select('.RateSection ')
        for name,price in zip(names,prices):

             yield  {
                "name":name.get_text(),
                "price":price.get_text()
              }
```